# Issue with in-fragment webview cookies validation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, webview

i used this code to auto-login in a website using webview (in fragment) , but it doesn't seem to work

```
WebView webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/");
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Cookie", "loggin_username=1;domain="URL";path=/;Expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2021 20:47:11 UTC;");
    headers.put("Cookie", "loggin_password=password;domain="URL";path=/;Expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2021 20:47:11 UTC;");

    webview.loadUrl("URL", headers);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

What am i doing wrong here ? 
Thank you for your help

Comment: It seems very unlikely that your web app will support authentication in this manner. The cookie is almost always a session identifier almost never a username and password. There is also CHAP but it's usage is different from what you are trying.

Comment: What do you recommend i have the username and password stored in sqlite , and i need to authenticate myself in webview ! any solution ?

Comment: First you need to create an authentication system for your webapp. That has nothing what so ever to do with android. You need to test that with your browser.